# Adding a count column in one data frame with the count of matches in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add a column to a data frame with the count of matches in another data frame, this seems pretty trivial but I can't seem to get it to work.  Example:

```
smaller_df$CountOfMatches <- nrow(subset(larger_df, Date == smaller_df$Date))
```

This gives me the error:

```
In `==.default`(Date, smaller_df$Date) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I know the data frames are different lengths, I'm not asking for a merge, I simply need for that for every row/date (valid date object) in the smaller_df; a count how many matches in the larger_df.

I'm very new to R so there must be something fundamental and very trivial I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have something working, its pretty ugly and I'm sure there is a better solution, so I think the question is still valid.  My hack is:                smaller_df$CountOfMatches <- apply(smaller_df, 1, function(row) { nrow(subset(larger_df, Date == row[1])) })

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what seems fairly straightforward:

```
smaller_df$bigDfCount <-sapply( smaller_df$Date,  
                        FUN=function(x) length(larger_df[larger_df$Date==x, "Date"] ) )
smaller_df

         Date bigDfCount
1  2000-01-01          4
2  2000-01-02          2
3  2000-01-03          5
4  2000-01-04          4
5  2000-01-05          5
6  2000-01-06          6
7  2000-01-07          2
8  2000-01-08          5
9  2000-01-09          3
10 2000-01-10          3
```

Comment: I probably would have used `sapply(smaller_df$Date, function(Dt) {sum(larger_df$Date==Dt)})`, but really the same same.

Comment: If you added `,na.rm==TRUE` then yours might be better than either of those.

Answer (score 4):

It is easiest to create a summary table and then merge that in with your original (smaller) data.  It's better to have a reproducible example.  So here is some reproducible data:

```
smaller_df <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), 
                                  as.Date("2000-01-10"), by="1 day"))
set.seed(5)
larger_df <- data.frame(Date=sample(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), 
                                        as.Date("2000-01-20"), by="1 day"),
                                    80, replace=TRUE))
```

Create the table (counts) of dates in `larger_df`

```
tbl <- table(larger_df$Date)
```

Convert this to a data.frame suitable for merging

```
counts <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(names(tbl)), CountOfMatches=as.vector(tbl))
```

And then merge on date. Note that if a date doesn't appear in `larger_df` but does in `smaller_df`, then the `CountOfMatches` will be `NA` rather than `0`.

```
merge(smaller_df, counts, all.x=TRUE)
```

For this sample data, you get

```
> merge(smaller_df, counts, all.x=TRUE)
         Date CountOfMatches
1  2000-01-01              4
2  2000-01-02              2
3  2000-01-03              5
4  2000-01-04              4
5  2000-01-05              5
6  2000-01-06              6
7  2000-01-07              2
8  2000-01-08              5
9  2000-01-09              3
10 2000-01-10              3
```

EDIT:

A more concise version which uses a package (which provides the convenience functions which get rid of some of the transformation details) is

```
library("plyr")
merge(smaller_df, 
      ddply(larger_df, .(Date), summarise, CountOfMatches=length(Date)),
      all.x = TRUE)
```

Same result and, effectively, the same logic. Also the same caveat about dates that don't appear in `larger_df`.

Comment: I think I will mark this as the answer (give it a day) although I'm still not happy.  Both current solutions to me seem convoluted, although it could be my imperative brain looking for a procedural like solution.  All this conversions from data frames to tables back to data frames just smells ugly to me.  I appreciate that this could be my personal biases (being new to the R way).  Anyway I prefer this to loading an additional package as anoop recommended.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do this using the data.table package. This is a package for handling large datasets efficiently in memory, allowing SQL-like or SAS data step-like manipulation, but the square brackets [] behave differently from data.frame objects. You can put data.table joins, expressions and aggregation within []. Read the data.table manual to find out more.

First, convert your two frames to data.table objects, and set the key column to be Date. The data.table objects will be sorted by Date, and can then be joined.

Using the same sample data as above:

```
library(data.table)
smaller_df <- data.table(data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), 
    as.Date("2000-01-10"), by="1 day")))
set.seed(5)
larger_df <- data.table(data.frame(Date=sample(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), 
    as.Date("2000-01-20"), by="1 day"), 80, replace=TRUE)))
```

Set the key column to be Date:

```
setkey(smaller_df, Date)
setkey(larger_df, Date)
```

You can use the by-without-by syntax and use the fact you have keyed by date. `.N` will return the number of rows in the subset (ie the number of rows where the dates match).

```
larger_df[smaller_df, .N]
##         Date   N
##  1: 2000-01-01 4
##  2: 2000-01-02 2
##  3: 2000-01-03 5
##  4: 2000-01-04 4
##  5: 2000-01-05 5
##  6: 2000-01-06 6
##  7: 2000-01-07 2
##  8: 2000-01-08 5
##  9: 2000-01-09 3
## 10: 2000-01-10 3
```